# Loop Cut failing some of the faces

Tags: faces

I'm trying to fix some shading issues by adding some geometry near that hole. The problem is that Loop Cut tool doesn't let me add a loop cut in the front faces, only at the back, why?

As you can see, I was able to add 2 cuts near the hole, but only at the back faces. I need the loop cut along that front face (by the yellow line).

Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: Are all affected and desired-to-be-affected faces quads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edgeloops are made of quads

If the tool doesn't suggest an edge is becuase those faces are not part of the edgeloop.

Cutting the faces with a boolean operation to create the hole transformed some of the quads in n-gon, that is currently breaking the quads flow around the section.

[image]

Comment: I see your point, so maybe I should create the loops before making the hole with the boolean modifier?

Comment: That's a way. Or you can use the knife tool, o just extude both ends...Or maybe you can fix those shading issue in another way (using sharp edges for example). The topology really depends on the purpose of the modeling. If you would add a more complete descriptions of your goals, the workflow you are going to follow, the issues you are going to face, etc...we can (maybe) suggest some best-practice ways.